# nytimes api error: must be int but not str

Tags: python, json

Hey there guys I was trying to gather information from the nytimes api but I'm getting this error: http://dpaste.com/3YKD9Z9

here's the code for the method I'm trying to use:

```
def fetcharticle(apikey, url):
    '''returns the JSON data of the most
    popular articles by view from the past 24 hours.'''
    parameters = {'api-key' : apikey}
    req = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    data = json.loads(req.content)
    parsedData = []
    newsData = {}
    for datum in data:
        newsData['title'] = data['results']['title']
        newsData['abstract'] = data['results']['abstract']
        newsData['section'] = data['results']['section']
        newsData['byline'] = data['results']['byline']
        newsData['views'] = data['results']['views']
    parsedData.append(newsData)
    return parsedData
```

and this is the url: http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/all-sections/1.json?

Comment: Judging from the error message, `data` seems to be a list, not a dictionary. Can you verify the contents of `data` or even `req.content`?

Comment: Looks like `data['results']` is a list, not a dict. So you cannot index it by `'title'`.

Comment: This is an example of Data: {
    "status": "OK",
    "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2015 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.",
    "num_results": 826,
    "results": [{
        "url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2015\/04\/26\/world\/asia\/nepal-earthquake-katmandu.html",
        "adx_keywords": "Earthquakes;Nepal;Katmandu (Nepal);United States Geological Survey",
        "column": "",
        "section": "World",
        "byline": "By ELLEN BARRY",

Comment: @Marorin `results` is indeed a list, @jwilner's answer will most likely solve your issues!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `results` is a list -- indexing into a list with a string raises that error.

```
a = []
a["Hi!"]  # Bam. Type error, trying to index into a list with a str.
```

This probably means you should be iterating over the results list. More generally, your code doesn't make sense. You want to declare the `newsData` dict within the loop so you don't constantly overwrite it. I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
for datum in data['results']:
    newsdata = {}
    newsData['title'] = datum['title']
    newsData['abstract'] = datum['abstract']
    newsData['section'] = datum['section']
    newsData['byline'] = datum['byline']
    newsData['views'] = datum['views']
    parsedData.append(newsData)
```

And this is still better written with a `dict` literal and proper pep8 formatting:

```
for datum in data['results']:
    news_data = {"title": datum["title"],
                 "abstract": datum["abstract"],
                 "section": datum["section"],
                 "byline": datum["byline"],
                 "views": datum["views"]}
    parsed_data.append(news_data)
```

Of course, then the question is why are you copying over so many of the fields from `datum` -- maybe you can just use the `datum` dict itself, and by extension, the `list` at the `results` key:

```
  parsed_data.extend(data['results'])
```

Comment: While this works, I'm trying to figure out how to get for example five different articles since this only gets one. Since I want to eventually get this JSON and push it over a template in a Django App.

Comment: @Marorin, I'm sorry, how does this only get one? As originally written, your code would constantly rewrite the keys in a single `dict`. That's why I moved the `dict` declaration within the loop. My code as written above would definitely get all of the articles out of the results list.

Comment: parsedData = []
    for datum in data['results']:
        new_data = {"title": datum["title"],
                "abstract": datum["abstract"],
                "section": datum["section"],
                "byline": datum["byline"],
                "views": datum["views"]}
    parsedData.append(new_data)
    return parsedData That's what I have in my code and I only get one article.

Comment: @Marorin, I can't really read this here because the whitespace is messed up, and it's of course important in Python. If you want to paste it above with better formatting, I'd check it out. Just guessing though -- did you put the `parsedData.append(new_data)` statement outside the `for` loop? That would produce the behavior you're describing. It needs to be inside the `for` loop to be called every time.